# Bspwm: resizing windows creates visual artifacts

Tags: nvidia, compton, bspwm

I'm having some problems when resizing certain windows in bspwm.

Examples:

- https://youtu.be/1uOcOCSVsvM. `Visual Studio Code`: this one is obvious
- https://youtu.be/PmRwh_S6gIY. 2 `Sublime Text` windows, tiled: This one is more subtle. You can see the scrollbars of both windows glitch out a bit. The right window is the most apparant.
- https://youtu.be/oDE-CUMr6fI. 2 `Thunar` windows, tiled: Same issue: you can see the right side of the right window glitch out.
- https://youtu.be/Zycu9PV6gMY. `Firefox` and `Konsole`, tiled: You can see the firefox window shows a white background when resizing. In the konsole window you can see the scrollbar glitches like the previous 2 points.
- https://youtu.be/UqDJcKurbiw. `gnome-terminal`, tiled: This one is really weird: I resize the window with `super`+`right-click`. Only when I release the right mouse button, it shows the resized window. Also when I keep moving the mouse, for example in circles as I did in the video, the window size keeps decreasing.

What I've tried:

- Testing without compton: same results
- Testing with the Nvidia GPU disabled in BIOS: same results
- Rebooting
- Setting `pointer_motion_interval` from 17 to 40: slight improvement but the problem doesn't go away. Any higher and resizing windows will lag.
- I use Nvidia's [DRM KMS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA#DRM_kernel_mode_setting) to eliminate tearing. I disabled it. Now I have the same problems, but with tearing.

I have no idea what to try next to troubleshoot this issue.

---

**Specs:**

```
OS: Arch Linux x86_64 
Host: 80WK Lenovo Y520-15IKBN 
Kernel: 5.0.13-arch1-1-ARCH 
Uptime: 7 hours, 9 mins 
Packages: 1653 (pacman) 
Shell: zsh 5.7.1 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
WM: bspwm 
Theme: OSX-Arc-Plus [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Papirus-Light [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: konsole 
Terminal Font: Hack 11 
CPU: Intel i7-7700HQ (8) @ 3.800GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile 
GPU: Intel HD Graphics 630 
Memory: 2234MiB / 7867MiB
```

Comment: I do not know how to fix that, I am sorry. I noticed that when you resize a window the other ones are automatically resized. Is this the default behaviour of Bspwm or is it easy to get it? I arrived here while looking if that is possiblein Bspwm.

Comment: @user1420303 Yes, that's the default in all tiling window mangers, including bspwm.

Comment: +1 Thank you. I just installed Bspwm and works fine. Some tiling wm do not behave in such way (e.g. qtile). I miss this feature that I used in others (like Sway), because of this I decided to switch.